# Strange rendering behavior in Electron app on OSX

Tags: css, macos, electron

I have a web app that is packaged with Electron to run on Macs, but for some reason on one of our Macs, the application isn't clearing parts of the screen when updates occur.

For example, we have an animated gif of a robot that waves his arm up and down. On the Mac, his arm is displayed in both places (as if both frames are being rendered on top of one another). The robot is also moved between being large and centered and being small and in a corner, but when this transition happens, the large robot sticks to the center of the screen (as well as in the corner where it's supposed to be) for a few seconds before being cleared.

The Mac is running OSX 10.10.5.

I'm not experiencing this issue in the Web, Windows, Linux, iOS, or Android builds.

Comment: Can you reproduce the issue in Chrome?

Comment: @VadimMacagon I'm going to try that. I updated the Mac to El Capitan which fixed the issue. I realize now that was a mistake because I can't test fixes without first figuring out how to downgrade the Mac.